# Static/Noise Animation using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, css

So I have just explored a whole new bunch of websites at [Awwwards](http://awwwards.com). One of them that particularly blew my mind was [this](http://district13.co.in/). I have just done some basic to intermediate CSS stuff. I was wondering how are these guys getting that noise/disturbance for their fonts ? I am totally clueless. Tried inspecting the code, couldn't understand much.

I know I am not capable of building the whole thing anytime soon, but I love the idea of the noisy background.

How to I go about this? Any pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: they're using canvas :)

Comment: canvas :D http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp Some information about canvas!

Comment: It's mainly done with JS, CSS plays quite a minimal part in this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is Lucas Bebber's Glitch SVG effect.

Here is [`original and working demo`](http://codepen.io/lbebber/details/ypgql/)

Here is `code snippets`

```css
body {
  background: black;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}
.glitch {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@keyframes noise-anim {
  $steps: 20;
  @for $i from 0 through $steps {
    # {
      percentage($i*(1/$steps))
    }
    {
      clip: rect(random(100)+px, 9999px, random(100)+px, 0);
    }
  }
}
.glitch:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 red;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  animation: noise-anim 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
@keyframes noise-anim-2 {
  $steps: 20;
  @for $i from 0 through $steps {
    # {
      percentage($i*(1/$steps))
    }
    {
      clip: rect(random(100)+px, 9999px, random(100)+px, 0);
    }
  }
}
.glitch:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 blue;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="glitch" data-text="GLITCH">GLITCH</div>
```

Comment: WOW. This is more than what I need .Thanks a bunch .I just wanted direction. Its hilarious how people attack you with down vote. Am I not understanding some kind of community policy ? I felt this question was in right interest.

Comment: some devs are just grumpy I guess

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi I think it because the answer is not related to the question. Like me, I found this page hoping to get what i need (Creating Noise with HTML5 Canvas), but the accepted answer use CSS clip-path instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

They're using HTML5 Canvas to create that noise animation, its drawn with Javascript rather than CSS which is why you wouldn't be able to work it out from inspecting it.

Here's a tutorial on how to create static/noise textures:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-generate-noise-with-canvas--net-16556

And here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/vX7NK/

I believe this part of the code is creating the random static:

```
buffer32[i++] = ((255 * Math.random())|0) << 24;
```

Might be worth also watching some intros to HTML5 Canvas too like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS1mD9Z0h-Q