# Animated noise effect with low CPU usage

Tags: javascript, css, animation, gif, cpu-usage

Here are a few methods I've found, but unsuitable for production because they use 100% CPU in today's browsers:

- [A 400x200 GIF](https://jsfiddle.net/w682epn6/embedded/result/), the smallest I found on the Internet.
- [Animating background position](https://jsfiddle.net/0LqoLp2s/embedded/result/), with a ~7K low-quality 192x192 jpeg image
- Canvas, example here: `http://stackoverflow.com/a/27312640/1058140`

So, does anybody know any way to get a decent CPU usage for this effect?

About 15 years ago, we did the same effect in school using Turbo Pascal on a 386 computer. I find it funny that in 2015 the most advanced software ever invented (browsers) are incapable of matching the same performance on better hardware :)

Comment: browsers are hardly the most advanced software; they sat dormant for 10 years... svg might be worth a try, it usually paints faster than html for the same CPU...

Comment: Are you talking about the "feTurbulence" SVG filter? I remember I used that in a different project to mix noise with the background and noticed that it affected the rendering time of the page by 0.2 - 0.5s (slower resizing, scrolling etc). And that was without any animation. Also, I noticed any SVG with 10-15 filters that resembles a really light Photoshop document, made Chrome unresponsive or crashed it

Comment: im not talking about filters, just a bunch of rectangles and way to alter them over time.

Comment: I have a 5 year old quad core AMD, so, quite modestly powered, and a mid range amd video card (in case GPU acceleration is in effect) - not one of those links resulted in CPU usage for firefox of even 1% ... your 100% CPU usage is coming from some other part of your code

Comment: No it's not. Same happens on other computers. You must have a good graphics card or you're viewing the page in a small window. Try on a 1080p display.