# Remove solid background on animation with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have followed the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312442/static-noise-animation-using-html5-canvas) to make noice animation in pure CSS and HTML5.

It is working fine when background have solid color, but how i can make this look good on movie background?

You can see the page in question [here](https://optin.dk/).

If you look closely you wil notice the black background ontop on movie. 
If i remove or make background transparent, it will change general style to more "boldish" look, which is not what i am looking for.

Can i archieve what i want using only css and html or do i need to use some javascript etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a property of the "glitch" animation you are using.

The :before has an offset of -2px and :after has an offset of 2px.
This makes the text look bolder by 4px together.

When the background is solid, then the :after hides the real text and the :before thus it looks like it has a glitch.

But if you do not hide the content with the background color, then indeed, it looks like bold.

Depending on the effect you intend to have, you may want to play with the clip values in the keyframes and make the original color transparent:

```
.glitch { color: transparent; }
.glitch::before { background: transparent; }
.glitch::after { background: transparent; }
```

Then play with the clip value of the keyframes (as you already did probably) in order to achieve the desired result.

Note that this will certainly produce another effect and it may no longer be what you are looking for. But the glitch technique you used is relying on the background to partially hide the text.